# Glitch at starting in recorded sound(16KHz) data using java program

Tags: java, audio-recording, javasound

We are doing experiment by recording sounds of frequencies higher than 16KHz. The recorder program is written in JAVA using java.sound package. In recorded data there is a unnecessary high amplitude glitch, which is disturbing the analysis of data. I don't know the reason of this behavior of the recorder as this is not always, sometimes recoding is perfect, without any such glitch.
What is the reason of this kind of behavior of the recorder?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what might be the cause. One possibility to consider is that the recording program commences after the sound is in progress, and the "glitch" is coming from the sudden onset of the sound already in progress. Sometimes, it is helpful to "prime" java audio code, so that it is running from RAM rather than from compiled code.

An abrupt start of the sound could also cause an initial transient. Is there a way to start your sound with a volume ramp-up? Even as little as 50 or 100 frames of transition (maybe less) can help with that.

16KHz is rather high. What is your sampling rate? There may be additional complications due to aliasing if you surpass the Nyquist value. For example, the sound may contains harmonic content that is above the Nyquist, as it is difficult to find filters with a really steep cutoff.